# Android Volley API UTF-8

Tags: android, utf-8, android-volley

How can I get the arabic text in a page's source code using Android Volley API??

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it possible that changing the returned default charset in `com.android.volley.toolbox.HttpHeaderParser` and there the method `parseCharset` can help you?

Something like

```
   /**
     * Returns the charset specified in the Content-Type of this header, or the
     * UTF-8 if none can be found.
     */
    public static String parseCharset(Map<String, String> headers) {
        String contentType = headers.get(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE);
        if (contentType != null) {
            String[] params = contentType.split(";");
            for (int i = 1; i < params.length; i++) {
                String[] pair = params[i].trim().split("=");
                if (pair.length == 2) {
                    if (pair[0].equals("charset")) {
                        return pair[1];
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return HTTP.UTF_8;
    }
```